# Getting one to many relationship in one query using json

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Let's assume we have two simple tables `cars` and `owners`. Each car can have many owners. We can fetch all car and their owners using foreign key in two queries but how about doing it in one single query? Each connection with MySQL is fairly expensive so I've come to solution using `data group` and `json`.

```
select 
  cars.id,
  CARS.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"id":"',owners.id,'", "name":"', owners.name, '"}')) owners
from cars
join owners 
  ON cars.id = owners.car_id
group by owners.car_id
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a62711/3

**It works fine but are there any disadvantages of this approach?** One thing that comes to my mind are some restriction about result field length. Are there any? Should I prepare my query to break if `owners.name` would contains illegal char like quotation mark or apostrophe? What should I take into account?

Comment: Yes there are read [*docs*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) first

Answer (score 0):

> are there any disadvantages of this approach?

Yes:

1. `GROUP CONCAT` will truncate the result "to the maximum length that is given by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable" (see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)).
2. The JSON will break if any of the names contains quotation marks or ends with escape characters.

One way to handle this instead is to use a simple join to select all the rows (ordering by car), then loop through them in your application and split them into groups when the car changes (e.g. https://gist.github.com/theodorejb/321a389bc612b4289ccc).